# Link List items with data role pages

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I need some help because the last couple of days I tried but I can't figure it out. 
I create with a loop different list items. It has this format:

```
<li><a href="page1"><h3>Page 1</h3><p>Open page 1</p></a></li>
```

So you can see this page has a href to page1, the other items have links to page2, page3 ect.

How can I create with a loop in the different pages with this code:

```
<div data-role="page1" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content"><p>This is Page 1</p></div>
</div>
```

I thought something like this but this isn't working:

```
jQuery(function($) {          
    var b = $('body');           
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)          
    {                    
        $('<div data-role="page1" id="page1"><div data-role="content"><p>This is Page '+i+'</p></div></div>').appendTo(b).page();     
    }    
});
```

Comment: What is this `.page()` method? I've never seen it.

Comment: your data-role="page1" should be data-role="page" as page will never change. This is jQM's markup for display not navigation

Comment: Understand and changed but I get everytime "Error Loading Page". The href can't find the page. Could it be that this is because the list is first is created?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how I get something like this done in an other way?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
        $('<div data-role="page'+i+'" id="page'+i+'"><div data-role="content"><p>This is Page '+i+'</p></div></div>').appendTo(b);
```

Comment: No, get an error when click on list item "Error Loading Page"

Comment: data-role="page'+i+'" should be data-role="page"